# How to read SSAD Traces (.trc files) without using SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server, ssas, trace

I have been having difficulties to open the traces (.trc files) using the function fn_trace_gettable. The traces being generated are from SSAS cubes and I have no diffculty to open it in SQL Server Profiler. I have bunch of trace files and I can’t just sit and load each one of the traces into a table separately. I need to automate this and thus want to write a package/code to avoid this.

I have read most of the online forums  but no luck.

Your few tips or guidance would be much helpful.

-Amit